# Background missing for the main nav links (Questions/Tags/etc)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-interface

Probably stating the obvious here, but below is what I'm seeing.

Probably from a recent update? Unless my PC is on crack? Checked it in FF 3.6.13 and IE8.

[image]

Comment: I can't repro that - what browser etc?

Comment: I put the browsers up there. Still doing it as of now.

Comment: This looks similar to [what happened back in December](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/954/whats-up-with-the-new-colors). hobodave's screenshot from back then shows the same symptoms as here.

Answer (score 1):

We can't reproduce this -- perhaps it was a temporary build or network issue?

Comment: Very strange. Still doing it for me. Just checked another system offsite via remote desktop, doing it there as well. In that case, FF 3.6.12 and IE8 on Server 2008.

Comment: Wait - I just refreshed (both places) and it is working. Please tell me I'm not crazy and it was fixed, because I definitely had Ctrl+F5'd several times before now.

Comment: @zanlok err.. uhh.. have you lost some weight? did you get a new haircut?

Comment: I didn't say it was *me* on crack, but my computer. Haha.

Comment: @zanlok we were seeing some file copy issues on the web farm so it probably wasn't just you... *as far as you know*